# Building common dependencies with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Assuming I have a set of images which depend on a common base image:

- base (this is only a set of common dependencies)

  ```sh
  FROM ubuntu:16.04

  ENV FOO 1
  ```
- child1

  ```sh
  FROM mybaseimage  # where mybaseimage corresponds to base

  CMD ["bar1_command"]
  ```
- child2

  ```sh
  FROM mybaseimage  # where mybaseimage corresponds to base

  CMD ["bar2_command"]
  ```

Is it possible to create `docker-compose` file which would build `base` without running it? Lets say I have following dependencies:

```
version: '2'
services:
    child1:
        build: ./path-to-child1-dockerfile
services:
    child2:
        build: ./path-to-child2-dockerfile
    depends_on:
        - child1
```

I would like `base` to be build even if it is not explicitly started. Is something like this even possible? Or should I simply use external Makefile to build dependencies?

```
build_base:
    docker build -t mybaseimage mybaseimage  

build_all: build_base
    docker-compose build
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use a Makefile. docker-compose is not designed to build chains of images, it's designed for running containers.

You might also be interested in [dobi](http://dnephin.github.io/dobi/) which is a build-automation tool (like make) designed to work with docker images and containers.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of **dobi**

Answer (score 36):

It's possible. There's a kind of workaround. You're close, but you were missing explicit image tags (so you had little ability on child images to declare which image you inherited from).

```yml
version: '3.2'
services:
  base:
    image: mybaseimage
    build: ./path-to-base-dockerfile
  child1:
    build: ./path-to-child1-dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - base
  child2:
    build: ./path-to-child2-dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - base
```

Let's say you have no images built. You run `docker-compose up`. The following things will happen:

- docker-compose sees that child1 and child2 services depend on base. So it will deploy base first.
- docker-compose sees that you have not yet tagged any image as `mybaseimage`. It knows how to build `mybaseimage` (you gave it a build path), so it will build it now, and tag it as `mybaseimage`.
- docker-compose deploys the `base` service.

  - ideally you should design `base` so that it quits immediately, or has no entrypoint. since we don't *actually* want it to run this service.
- docker-compose considers deploying child1 and child2
- docker-compose sees that you have not yet tagged any image as `child1`. It knows how to build `child1` (you gave it a build path), so it will build it now, and tag it as `child1`.
- docker-compose deploys the `child1` service
- same sequence of steps for child2

The next `docker-compose up` will be simpler (we have tagged images available, so we skip all build steps).

If you already have tagged images, and want to rebuild: use `docker-compose build` to tell it to build all images (yes, base and children will both be rebuilt).

Comment: This seems to work: If you don't want `base` to run, just don't give it a CMD.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me: Docker tries to *build* both images simultaneously, seems like `depends_on` is relevant only in terms of runtime

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to make your dockerfile a multi stage build:

```
FROM ubuntu as builder
...


FROM builder as my_target_1
...
CMD my_cmd_1

FROM builder as my_target_2
...
CMD my_cmd_2
```

If your `builder` is very large, but you only need a couple of files from it, you could also do:

```
FROM ubuntu as builder
...

FROM alpine as my_target_1
COPY --from=builder /path/to/exec /root/exec
...
COM my_cmd_1
```

Then, in your docker compose file, you can do:

```yaml
services:
    my_target_1:
        build:
            dockerfile: path/to/Dockerfile
            target: my_target_1
    my_target_2:
        builder:
            dockerfile: path/to/Dockerfile
            target: my_target_2
```

If you really want the `builder` to also be part of your dockerfile (e.g. to push to a registry) without running it, you can add a `profiles` tag, which will assigne a profile to the target:

```
servies:
    builder:
        build:
            dockerfile: path/to/Dockerfile
            target: builder
        profiles: ["do-not-run"]
```

This will make `builder` part of the `do-not-run` profile, which means:

- if you just do `docker compose up`, it won't be run
- you can make it run by doing `docker compose up --profile=do-not-run`

In any case (weather you have the `builder` in your `docker-compose.yml` or not), you can build everything using

```
docker compose build
```

Comment: Looks interesting solution. Will try.

Answer (score -5):

You don't need separate images for this problem - just use an environment variable:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

ENV PROGRAM

CMD ${PROGRAM}
```

Then for container 1, set environment variable `PROGRAM` to `bar1_command`. Do the same for container 2, 3, ..., N.